# MVC 5 partial view as jQuery dialog using knockout

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout-mvc

I am using knockout to render a page with rows of data. On each row there is a link which should call a controller function which returns a partial view.

knockout script for link is (inside foreach loop)...

```
<a class="lnkEdit" data-bind="attr: {'href': '@Url.Action("ControllerActionName", new RouteValueDictionary() { { "Controller", "ControllerName" } })/'+ id}">Details</a>
```

Script section...

```
        $(document).ready(function () {            
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
            title: 'Details',
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            position: ['center', 50],
            width: 700,
            show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                $(this).load(url);
            }
        });

        $(".lnkEdit").on("click", function (e) {
            url = $(this).attr('href');                
            $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
            return false;
        });

        $("#btncancel").on("click", function (e) {
            $("#dialog-edit").dialog("close");
            return false;
        });

        ko.applyBindings(new UnitViewModel());
    })
```

My page has div as place holder for dialog...

```
<div id="dialog-edit" style="display: none">
```

Problem: When I click on link for details; the controller returns partial view but jquery is not able to generate dialog so the page opens as normal view. What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 2):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I'll Check Your code and is working... 
just add CSS and JS proper.

Comment: Was away therefore could not check; will update once I check my references.

Comment: I get the same; no dialog popup. I hope that you have tested the code with knockout and MVC.

Comment: i tested in MVC 5 and Knockout ViewModel

Comment: I am loading scrips using _Layout file. And the order of js files are as you have mentioned but still dialog window is not displayed rather new page is loaded.